# SAS Loop or Array with variable name Suffix

Tags: sas

I have to 2 tables, T1 contains 10 variables and T2. contains 100 variables. I have to do sum by multiplying T1 10 variables with T2 of same 10 variables with last name only changes. I want to keep the varible names in loop and to output as TOTAL_.

Ex: **app** will replace with: store, ramp, abhi, coast,recyc, ind etc.

```
proc sql;
create table OHDT as 
select T2.Model,T2.Age,

sum( T1.Com_Pass   * T2.Com_Pass_app
    ,T1.Com_Frt    * T2.Com_Frt_app
    ,T1.Com_Other  * T2.Com_Other_app
    ,T1.BG_Corp    * T2.BG_Corp_app
    ,T1.BG_Fract   * T2.BG_Fract_app
    ,T1.BG_Gov     * T2.BG_Gov_app
    ,T1.BG_Other   * T2.BG_Other_app
    ,T1.BG_Owner   * T2.BG_Owner_app
    ,T1.BG_Part    * T2.BG_Part_app
    ,T1.mil_Agri   * T2.mil_Agri_app )   as Total_app,

from Market T1
inner join master T2
on 
T1.Model= T2.Model and T1.Age=T2.Age;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a macro to loop over your list and generate the SQL for you.

```
%macro create_OHDT(apps);
%let n=%sysfunc(countw(&apps));
proc sql;
create table OHDT as 
select T2.Model,T2.Age

%do i=1 %to &n;
%let app = %scan(&apps,&i);
,sum( T1.Com_Pass   * T2.Com_Pass_&app
    ,T1.Com_Frt    * T2.Com_Frt_&app
    ,T1.Com_Other  * T2.Com_Other_&app
    ,T1.BG_Corp    * T2.BG_Corp_&app
    ,T1.BG_Fract   * T2.BG_Fract_&app
    ,T1.BG_Gov     * T2.BG_Gov_&app
    ,T1.BG_Other   * T2.BG_Other_&app
    ,T1.BG_Owner   * T2.BG_Owner_&app
    ,T1.BG_Part    * T2.BG_Part_&app
    ,T1.mil_Agri   * T2.mil_Agri_&app )   as Total_&app

%end;
from Market T1
inner join master T2
on 
T1.Model= T2.Model and T1.Age=T2.Age;
quit;
%mend;
%create_OHDT(store ramp abhi coast recyc ind);
```

Comment: no problem.  Using a macro to loop over a list is a pretty common need.  Once you learn it you can do lots.